# Authentification via Facebook need two clicks in some cases

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to do login via FB. If I'm not logged in FB, everything works fine but if I'm logged in FB and I click on "login via facebook!" hyperlink the URL has changed on comething like this `fb2.php?code=AQAlKrGXWS2bhiZ-ZK7UPiDRLdVMjR84jAbxS41kW3I5h5P...` but I'm not logged and if I'm not login till I click second time. It's strange, isn't it? Could you someone help me? The source code is here.

```
 <?php session_start();
     define('APP_ID', 'my_api_id');
     define('APP_SECRET', 'my_app_secret');
     define('CANVAS_PAGE', 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxx/');
     define('CANVAS_URL', 'http://localhost/xxx/');

     require_once 'facebook.php';

     $facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => APP_SECRET, ));

     $user = $facebook->getUser();

     if(isset($user)) {
             try {
xtended_permission)
                     $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
             } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {        
                     $user = NULL;
             }
     }

  if ($user) {   $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' =>
 "http://metalradio.cz/metalRadioTesting/facebook-sdk/logout.php")); }
 else {   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(  array(
      'scope' => 'email'   ) ); }
     ?>

     <!doctype html>
     <html>
             <head>
                     <title>Facebook login</title>
                     <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
             </head>
             <body>
                             <?php
                             if(!is_null($user))
                                     echo "Name: " . $user_profile['email'];
                             ?>
                     <h2>Users authentification via FB</h2>
                     <?php if ($user):
                     ?>
                     <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl;?>">logout!</a>
                     <?php else:?>
                     <div>
                             <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl;?>">login via facebook!</a>
                     </div>
                     <?php endif?>
             </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: The code is broken after my pasate here, but in edit message is ok, admin please could you fix this? Thanks

Comment: I fixed it yet, I have got unfully adress in appdashboard. Now it works fine.